# Rewrite URLs in htaccess for multiple pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect urls from two different pages to readable URLS.
my .htaccess looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ blog-detail.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ blog-detail.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ page.php?pid=$1
```

The first urls using the blog-detail.php work fine. My URLS can be like mysite.com/latest-news-story

However, the second with page.php does not work unless I remove the blog-detail rewrite rules. How can I have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually combine your rules that check for terminating `/` into one.

So, you actually just need the following two rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/-]+)/?$ page.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ blog-detail.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I wish to pass a request like mysite.com/latest-news-article to blog-detail and a request like mysite.com/new-page to page.php. With my current rule, only the first rule works, in this case, it passes all request to blog-detail ignoring page.php

Comment: Please outline your link formats in more detail. How do you want the server to distinguish between latest-news-article and new-page? And, do you see the `/` in between `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`? That means you're expecting URLs like `mysite.com/part1/part2`.

Comment: I suppose in this fashion, the server cannot distinguish the two. Can you only push rewrite requests to one file/url?

Comment: No, you can push the requests to different urls but you need to differentiate which requests should go to which url. For e.g, you may say that if url starts with latest the go to blog, if not go to page. But I need to know this from you as I can't guess what's your requirement exactly.

Comment: ok, My blog pages are set up to use text slugs, they will usually look something like mysite.com/funny-story-about-nothing and direct to blog-detail. For pages, they will often look like mysite.com/news or mysite.com/contact. So, they are both text based and using the text slug to fetch the content from the DB.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that your pages would never contain `-` effectively restricting them to just one word links? This would also mean that your blog pages would always have two or more words in their titles.

Comment: yes! This will always be the case. and I will run code to make sure of this when adding records to the DB.

Comment: Take a look at the updated rules. Just the rules. Also, do you see the `/` in between `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` in your original rules? Are you expecting URLs like `mysite.com/part1/part2` because the current rules will not fire for them.

Comment: Im never expecting mysite.com/part1/part2, only mysite.com/title-of-news-story and mysite.com/testpage (oneword)

Comment: unfortunately not. All pages just redirect to blog-detail.php now and there is no data on the screen, just a error I display that says there are "no blogs"

Comment: Add `[QSA,L]` to both the rules as shown in my update.

Comment: same result, except now it redirects every page to page.php

Comment: Please, add the two rewrite conditions and it will fix the cross linking. Since, blog-detail had a `-` in itself it triggered the page.php rule as well. The above update will fix all such problems.